# Why can't I add this file to pending commits in git?

Tags: git

I have a submodule that `git diff` is reporting as `dirty`. So, I `cd` into the submodule's repo, check the `git status` and see that one file is reporting as changed.

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Main.cs
```

Doing a `git add Main.cs` or `git add --force Main.cs` does nothing. No messages are shown and git status reports the exact same.

Also this file doesn't match anything in `.gitignore`.

I don't even know where to go from here!

`git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1`

Comment: What about `git add -u`?

Comment: Are you trying `git add` from the submodule directory, or from the main repo directory? Do you have `ignorecase` set, and the file is actually called `main.cs` or `MAIN.CS` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of this:

- stash/unstash it
- copy file to another place, checkout it discarding changes, then replace freshly checked out file with saved one
- if nothing above helps, git rm' it and then add again

Answer (score 0):

what if you run 'git gui' from the commandline?

the file should show up on in the unstaged list. clicking on the file's icon should move it to the staged list.

Does that stage the Main.cs file when you run 'git status'?

If so this should also be an easy workaround.